# Is it cool to have "fun" comment-discussions unrelated to an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

An example can be found under this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/545), where a discussion based on "My main purpose of being here is in collecting the votes. I'd even go further and say that this is my main purpose in life." is going on (I guess for fun), but personally I had to consume some of my time until figuring out that these somewhat upvoted comments were totally unrelated to the answer.

So it cool to have these *chats* under posts, or should they strictly limited in chat?

I thought no, but the number of the upvotes in these comments, made me ask, so that I know when to flag a comment or not in sites that I am experienced in (e.g., Stack Overflow), in future cases (without putting more unneeded work in mods).

Comment: FWIW, I flagged the post requesting for comment clean-up since the comments that are really asking for clarification (from year 2014) are hidden due to the older chatty comments...

Comment: Doesn't this oppose to the answer posted here @andmyself?

Comment: I have my own principle on comment clean-up that I follow, but let's just see how it goes

Comment: I see @andmyself, if you want to share it in an answer, I promise to read it.

Comment: I made a mostly irrelevant comment on Skeptics, pointing out the hypocrisy of a certain claim. It got uovoted a few times and then deleted. There's not too much harm in making them (not as a habit) imo. If there are important comments, they should probably be edited into the post or added as an answer. Either way, you can flag as "no longer needed" and if the site mods agree, the comments will be deleted.

Comment: I follow the same approach @TheWanderer. If the comment is off-topic, I make sure to delete afterwards, in a reasonable timeframe. I see your point about exceptions. If "Pan Metron Ariston" was still around in the world, I think it would apply..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strictly speaking, they do not help improving the post (comments' main and only purpose) and can (should) be deleted. However, many sites have a more relaxed attitude towards chatty comments, which as you note is reflected in the score. This is one of the areas where communities are permitted to deviate from the norm.

So **as a non-member** of that community, I would **definitely not** flag them.

Comment: On the other hand, if the comments impacted someone’s ability to understand the state of the question and its answers, shouldn’t we make the mod team aware of the negative impact regardless of our community membership? The information on SE sites should be useful even to people landing on that page from a search engine and community standards on comment hygiene really shouldn’t be prioritized over that.

Comment: @ColleenV one of the members of my example is a mod. Given the "it depends on the relaxivity of the site whether it is allowed or not", I think that the people in charge is OK (and I am OK, as long as SE people are happy).